# Action script on one tab only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

trying to get a script to only run on one tab, rather than impact all tabs - this one seems to be having an impact across multiple tabs for some reason.

Have tried declaring the name of the tab, which in this case would be: 
**"1. Scheduling"** 
but it breaks down and I get errors when trying to run the script. Any ideas?

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("3. Current_Team")

  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){

    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

      var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();

      var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

        if(makeIndex != 0) {

      var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);

  }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){ 
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='1. Scheduling')return;
  var datash=e.source.getSheetByName("3. Current_Team")
  if(e.range.columnStart==4 && e.range.rowStart>1){
    e.range.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    var makes=datash.getRange(1, 1, 1, datash.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var makeIndex=makes[0].indexOf(e.value) + 1;
    if(makeIndex != 0) {
      var validationRange = datash.getRange(3, makeIndex, datash.getLastRow());
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}
```